# BitmapFactory.decodeFile() ENOENT I/O Exception

Tags: android, file, io, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I save a camera image on a prefixed path like:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+/*myFolder&myFileName*/;
```

Which is correctly saved in

```
/storage/emulated/0/myapp/target060613_112341.jpg
```

Then I'd like to put this image in a ImageView using this code:

```
public void addImageToGallery(String path) {
    ImageView imv = new ImageView(mGUIView.getContext());
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    imv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    imv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imv.setMaxHeight(100);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeImageGallery);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
    rl.addView(imv, lp);
}
```

But there is a problem when BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path) is called... the function return an error saying that there is no such file or directory (ENOENT)

I have also w/r permissions in my manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Same error if I try to store and retrieve the jpg file on the internal path (`getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`)

Comment: You could try to `System.out.println("Path = "+path.toString());` just before the decode file, to check if the path is still correctly at that point.

Comment: because your path is null..

Comment: the String path arrives correctly...
 06-06 12:03:23.774: E/AR(6264): image path: /storage/emulated/0/myapp/target060613_120323.jpg
06-06 12:03:23.804: E/AR(6264): image path to bitmap: /storage/emulated/0/myapp/target060613_120323.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved adding in the manifest file:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Comment: Utter nonsense - **there are no such permissions**, and even if there were, they would have nothing to do with your attempt to access the **external** storage.